# for Loops in C++ with Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My teacher introduced us to looping through an array in the following format:

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int *garbage = new int[size];
for (int* p = garbage; p < (garbage + size); p++) {
    if (*p > *max) {
        max = p;
    }
}
```

I understand what's going on, but it's just odd to me as a new concept. Are there better ways of going through an array like this?

Second Question: do you have to turn every pointer to a nullptr once you are done with it? For example, does it cause memory leaks to have that for loop like that with the pointer p or does it self destruct once it leaves the for loop scope?

Comment: Best way is to not use an array at all. Look up `std::vector`. Mind you since `std::vector` initializes all elements, you can't use it to inspect garbage like this.

Comment: `do you have to turn every pointer to a nullptr once you are done with it?` No. Setting a pointer to `nullptr` doesn't do much other than make accidental use after nulling it easier to detect on most systems as it would be instantly fatal. `setting a pointer to `nullptr` does nothing whatsoever to free memory. Nor does letting `p` go out of scope. When you dynamically allocate something with `new` or `new[]` you have to manually return it with `delete` or `delete[]` to prevent leaking.

Comment: The rule of thumb in Modern C is to reserve use of `new` to rare edge cases where it cannot be avoided. You will find containers like the aforementioned `std::vector` and [Smart Pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) very helpful in managing memory. Also read up on the concept of Resource Ownership.

Comment: The word `new` without a `delete` should make your teacher cringe. Look at RAII. Good stuff.

Comment: Well, there is a delete I just didn't add it. And I've read that vectors should be used when you have to, but I can't avoid it for the purpose of school assignments

Comment: @CarterMitchell an end run around the "No `vector` " rule in many introductory courses is to write and use your own simple `vector` clone. Doing it and doing it right can be very educational, and you'll probably have to do it for an assignment sooner or later. Might as well get started early.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit cleaner to do this:

```
int size = 10, max = 0;
int *mem = new int[size];
int *end = mem + size;
for (int *p = mem; p < end; p++)
    if (*p > max)
        max = *p;
```

But if you start using C++11 you can do this:

```
int max = 0;
std::vector<int> mem;
for (auto &i : mem)
    if (i > max)
        max = i;
```

There are probably even easier ways using other std namespace tools.

> do you have to turn every pointer to a nullptr once you are done with it?

No, but it helps a lot when debugging. If you use a freed pointer that wasn't set to nullptr you'll be a lot more confused than if it is nullptr. Setting the pointer to nullptr doesn't actually automatically free the memory. You still have to call the appropriate 'free' function before setting to nullptr.

Comment: Second one's groovy, but since `std::vector` initializes  all of its elements finding the max stored value is going to be trivial.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out t that asker that setting the pointer to `nullptr` does nothing whatsoever to free the memory. In fact it makes it harder to free it as you no longer have the address you need to free.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are better (as in - more readable) ways of iterating through an array. For instance:

```
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    if (p[index] > *max) {
        max = &p[index];
    }
}
```

However, as you see in the `max = ...` assignment, it's easier to have a pointer to an element of an array if you want to pass it on to another pointer variable.

Regarding your second question - there is no inherent value in setting it to `nullptr`. However, to prevent memory leaks, you should deallocate (free) the memory you reserved with operator `new` by using the operator `delete` once you're done with the array, like so:

```
delete [] p;
```

EDIT: Please note that you won't be able to safely dereference the pointer `max` (meaning you can't read that `int` it's pointing to with `*max` expression) after you deallocate the array without causing Undefined Behavior and possibly crashing your program, because your program will return the reserved memory to the OS and won't have access to it.

Thanks to @user4581301 for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way of solving the problem. There's a C++ standard library algorithm for finding the maximum element in a range: [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). No hand-written loop is needed.

```
int max = *std::max_element(garbage, garbage + size);
```

Note that it returns an iterator (a pointer in this case) so I used `*` to get the value from the iterator.

Your teacher might not like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

> in C++11 you can do this:

```
int max = 0;
std::vector<int> mem;
for (auto &i : mem)
    if (i > max)
        max = i;
```

Comment: So copy and pasting someone else's answer? Nice.